# Slow loading of my site

Tags: silverstripe

I'm using silverstripe 3.0 on my webspace. Unfortunately the site loads extremly slow on the first request. (I added around 5-6 pages). With a second request the site loads faster. It seems that there is only a problem when the site is called the first time - till the pages are cached. Any suggestions/help regarding the performance? Thank you

Comment: the info here could help you - but with the menu caching you probable cannot use "$LinkingMode"
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/silverstripe-dev/u0bKdvYgYhM

Comment: If there's a good answer, you could mark it to help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to your .htaccess file in the root directory.

http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/5278be6917229

It should speed up your page a little bit.

You also should combine all your css files to one and all your js files to one file. You can do this automatically with Silverstripe.

Also save all your images for the web or use Yahoo SmushIt!

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this might be server configuration related:

[First page request on website very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052186/first-page-request-on-website-very-slow)

The website doesn't get so many hits so the server kills resources from the server and needs to spool them back again.

Also quickly googled this article that should help find the possible cause:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97842/universal-problem-first-request-after-25-second-inactivity-always-slower-1-s